# css sprite images not clickable in ie9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-sprites

I have created a button with `<a>` tag and a span nested inside. The span holds the icon of the  button: I used background image which is sprite image.

On chrome and FF all works great, but in IE9 the image of the button isn't clickable. I.e., when I click the so-called icon nothing happens - no action or styling appear.

Below is my HTML for the button:

```
<a class="btn"  href="#" title="Cancel">
    <span class="icon iconCancel"></span>Cancel
</a>
```

#### I had updated my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EWppd/20/

Thanks!

Comment: What is supposed to happen? (Your fiddle isn't really helpful.)

Comment: when clicking the button ( also on the image ) it should trigger the :active state. it works in chrome and FF but not in IE9, where it trigger the active state only when clicking on the area around the image.

Comment: Not seeing a problem.  I've applied a style for `:active` and it works just fine in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to work fine here... Just try to declare Width and Height on your css on your span that holds the icons and test again.

Something like this:

```
.btn > span { 
display: inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
width:20px;
height:20px;
```

}

If not work, you can also try to use some z-index with a higher value on your "a" tag (though it shouldnt be necessary at all).

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle doesn't seem to illustrate the issue at all.

To do this you need to give width and height to the `a` and to the `span`, set the `a` to `position: relative` and the span to `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`. Then set the background image on the span, and shift its position when the `a` is hovered.

Comment: none of the solutions worked. I've also noticed that some other buttons ( not my dev ) behave the same in Ie9 - the image sprite area isn't clickable.

Comment: This is a pretty standard operation, so unless you can show us what you are doing, we can't help much. Anyhow, here's an example of this kind of image replacement: http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/navimagereplace.htm